# Help with translation, art

Tags: traditional-characters

First i want to apologize for no being perfect in English, i speak spanish, currently studying japanese and with plans of starting chinese next year.

Recently i bought a piece of chinese art at a flymarket in buenos aires and i can’t read the signature i have a chinese friend and he couldnt help me

https://ibb.co/TkF8mWT
https://ibb.co/hFQT5fd
https://ibb.co/dKBYBQ4

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

the title is “君子之風” (roughly, the demeanor of gentleman)

the next column is “于右任題” (written by mr 于), an important figure in last century)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu_Youren

the seal below this column is “右任”

右 is in the form of 又-手 [image]

< 
[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=右](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8F%B3)>

the bottom left characters are “縱材”, with the seal “縱材書畫”

have fun :)

Comment: yes, my error  answer edited.

Comment: Thank you, it really help me, is it okey if i keep posting about chinese art? I don’t know why but i seems to be a lot of chinese art in argentina, if it is okey please let me know

Comment: sure, ask the question “skilfully”, make it language related.